# Facebook user Authentication process

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

I am trying out this example http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

But I am getting xml error which says permission denied.

I have changed the application ID also. I am bit confused about the new UI of developers.facebook.com I was comfortable with the old UI.

I am not sure where I dont mention my call back url.

Kindly help me out.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var button;
            var userInfo;

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({ appId: '273713715982249', //change the appId to your appId
                    status: true, 
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    });

               showLoader(true);

               function updateButton(response) {
                    button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                    userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        //user is already logged in and connected
                        FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                            login(response, info);
                        });

                        button.onclick = function() {
                            FB.logout(function(response) {
                                logout(response);
                            });
                        };
                    } else {
                        //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                        button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                        button.onclick = function() {
                            showLoader(true);
                            FB.login(function(response) {
                                if (response.authResponse) {
                                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                        login(response, info);
                                    });    
                                } else {
                                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                    showLoader(false);
                                }
                            }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});   
                        }
                    }
                }

                // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
                FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol 
                    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());


            function login(response, info){
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    var accessToken                                 =   response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    userInfo.innerHTML                             = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name
                                                                     + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;
                    button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
                    showLoader(false);
                    document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
                }
            }

            function logout(response){
                userInfo.innerHTML                             =   "";
                document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML     =   "";
                document.getElementById('other').style.display =   "none";
                showLoader(false);
            }

            //stream publish method
            function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
                showLoader(true);
                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'stream.publish',
                    message: '',
                    attachment: {
                        name: name,
                        caption: '',
                        description: (description),
                        href: hrefLink
                    },
                    action_links: [
                        { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
                    ],
                    user_prompt_message: userPrompt
                },
                function(response) {
                    showLoader(false);
                });

            }
            function showStream(){
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    //console.log(response.id);
                    streamPublish(response.name, 'I like the articles of Thinkdiff.net', 'hrefTitle', 'http://thinkdiff.net', "Share thinkdiff.net");
                });
            }

            function share(){
                showLoader(true);
                var share = {
                    method: 'stream.share',
                    u: 'http://thinkdiff.net/'
                };

                FB.ui(share, function(response) { 
                    showLoader(false);
                    console.log(response); 
                });
            }

            function graphStreamPublish(){
                showLoader(true);

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', 
                    { 
                        message     : "I love thinkdiff.net for facebook app development tutorials",
                        link        : 'http://ithinkdiff.net',
                        picture     : 'http://thinkdiff.net/iphone/lucky7_ios.jpg',
                        name        : 'iOS Apps & Games',
                        description : 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'

                }, 
                function(response) {
                    showLoader(false);

                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
            }

            function fqlQuery(){
                showLoader(true);

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    showLoader(false);

                    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/
                    var query       =  FB.Data.query('select name, profile_url, sex, pic_small from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                    query.wait(function(rows) {
                       document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML =  
                         'FQL Information: '+  "<br />" + 
                         'Your name: '      +  rows[0].name                                                            + "<br />" +
                         'Your Sex: '       +  (rows[0].sex!= undefined ? rows[0].sex : "")                            + "<br />" +
                         'Your Profile: '   +  "<a href='" + rows[0].profile_url + "'>" + rows[0].profile_url + "</a>" + "<br />" +
                         '<img src="'       +  rows[0].pic_small + '" alt="" />' + "<br />";
                     });
                });
            }

            function setStatus(){
                showLoader(true);

                status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;
                FB.api(
                  {
                    method: 'status.set',
                    status: status1
                  },
                  function(response) {
                    if (response == 0){
                        alert('Your facebook status not updated. Give Status Update Permission.');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Your facebook status updated');
                    }
                    showLoader(false);
                  }
                );
            }

            function showLoader(status){
                if (status)
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
                else
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            }
```

This is the code I am using I am not to logiin but I am not getting the user information.

Comment: Can you post the exact error? And a link to a live example, or at least some code?

Comment: @Abby : https://s3.amazonaws.com/foofysfacebookapp/facebook.html here is the example link

Comment: @Abby here is the source code  https://github.com/mahmudahsan/New-JavaScript-SDK---OAuth-2.0-based-FBConnect-Tutorial

Comment: When do you get the error? Without seeing the code working, or knowing when/where the error is occurring, its hard to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has introduced Auth Dialog feature in Facebook application Setting page. Now you don’t need to write code to for user permissions. You can do it by configuring the right values in Application settings. get more details at http://iforapple.org/?p=436

Answer (score 1):

```
function fblogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
     if(response.session && response.perms){
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {

         });
     }
    }, {perms:''});//set the permissions
}
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '',//giv ur app id
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: This code will not work past tomorrow! You need to use oauth: true in your init, and response.authResponse instead of session!

Comment: I am now able to login but its not displaying user information at all and not giving any error as such.

Comment: @Pooja : even after using the code which u have provided, I am just able to login but its not displaying user information pooja :(

Comment: FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.email);
});

Comment: This code is confusing, there is an isolated </script> Also it gives syntax error